# Why is I18nManager.isRTL value is wrong? What can I do without reloading the app?

Tags: react-native, localization, internationalization, expo

I'm developing an expo app (react-native).

I've been learning about `I18nManager` and `expo-localization`

When my app is launched in LTR language there is no problem.
My problem is when my app is launched in RTL language, and the `I18nManager` get **wrong** value of `isRTL` right, and therefor my whole app is flipping. In contrast, the `expo-localization` does get the value `isRTL` **correct**. I know about `allowRTL` and `forceRTL`, for now I don't want to use them.

I just want to know why `I18nManager` gets wrong value of `isRTL` in contrast to the `expo-localization` that does get it right.